# Kafka topic have no duplication on messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How to achieve such outcome with messages in kafka topics?

I.e changelog-like functionality - have multiple messages coming into the topic, but I only care about the last one that came in.

Also what happens in the case topic is partitioned?

#### Is it possible in Kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you should set `cleanup.policy` for this topic to `compact`, as shown below:

CREATE TOPIC:

> bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic my-topic --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact

UPDATE TOPIC:

> bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name my-topic --alter --add-config cleanup.policy=compact

With `compact` policy set, you have to assign a key for every message and Kafka producer will partition messages based on that key.

Comment: What happens if I have multiple partitions of the topic? The message with the same key will be routed to the same partition all the time?

Comment: also compaction happens immediately or in batches over period of time? For example I sent message with key="A" into topic, it's unique. 2 seconds later it got the same message with key="A" in the same topic. If I query the kafka immediately after - will I see 2 records or 1 record?